# Impossible CDI injecting of SLF4 Logger through @Produces

Tags: logging, jboss7.x, cdi, slf4j, weld

I am wondering where is the problem with injecting of org.slf4j.Logger into REST service in web app using Jboss 7.1. I have added beans.xml also.

That is my producer class:

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class LoggerProducer {

@Produces
public Logger producer(InjectionPoint ip) {
    return LoggerFactory.getLogger(ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
  }
}
```

And how I am trying to use Logger :

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.validation.ValidateRequest;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

@ValidateRequest
@RolesAllowed("admin")
@Path("domains")
public class DomainRestService {

     @Inject
     private DomainBean domainService;
     @Inject
     private Logger log;
```

But when I try to deploy my application, deployment fails with the following exception :

```
 Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Logger] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private com.gbs.acc.service.rest.DomainRestService.log]
```

I have seen many examples for Logger CDI injection but I cant understand why doesnt work ?

Answer (score 4):

You should use `javax.enterprise.inject.Produces` instead of `javax.ws.rs.Produces` to annotate the `producer` producer method in the `LoggerProducer` class.

Comment: :))  Netbeans shortcut has added incorrect import for me. Thank you very much.